# Flutter/Dart API Call Throws Error (sometimes)

Tags: flutter, dart

APIs:

1. https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY
2. https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=BANKNIFTY

API Call Method:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';

import '../Models/fetched_data.dart';

Future<FetchedData?> fetchIndexDetails(String index) async {
  final String url =
      'https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=$index';

  try {
    final response = await get(
      Uri.parse(url),
    );

    final FetchedData? fetchedData = fetchedDataFromJson(response.body);
    return fetchedData;
  } catch (e) {
    print('$index Error: $e');
  }
  return null;
}
```

The json file is same for both the APIs, hence the model class too.

However, the second API call works smoothly but the first API call throws an error saying:

```
type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int?'
```

Can anybody help me decode the problem here? Much tia :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a JSON parsing issue for unmatched type parsing of the API and the your Dart Model ..

How to diagnose it?
You can always catch those errors while the development by enabling the dart debugger for uncaught exceptions, which gives you exactly the broken casting

[image: How to enable dart debugger for uncaught exceptions]

Comment: Thanks :) I was able to find the codes where they're breaking

Comment: Happy to hear that, 

@ManishPaul It would be great if you accept the answer so that any developers get the issue reason using the Dart debugger, without the need to blindly scan the code.

Answer (score 1):

`type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int?'`

The API has returned a `double` value where an `int` is expected.

In your model or where appropriate replace the expected type to use `num` which `int` and `double` are both subtypes of

Answer (score 0):

Check your model class where you have defined different variables and match with data type you are getting in response from the json.
There must be a variable you have defined in model class as int? but u r getting double as a response so u got to convert the data type .

Comment: I did cross-check this way... but everything seems fine..

Comment: Ok you can try changing the type of variables in model class to num and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to map a double to int?, the response had a double and you are assigning it to int?, add a breakpoint when mapping the response to see the corresponding field. You can try casting it to int or just changing the type all together.